# How to make this menu bar fixed while scrolling?

Tags: html, css, menu, menubar

I want to fix this menu bar at the top of the page, so that when user scrolls down, the menu bar continues to appear and the content flows into it. I tried everything, some help would be nice.

Heres the CSS and below the HTML:

CSS: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a0z0eov71wvha1c/style.css

HTML: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qyvb0oqhx8550ym/html.txt

Thank you!

Comment: make jsfiddle with only code that is related...nobody wants to read stuff that in the end is not even going to be helpful. And you would know what parts are irrelevant. But others don't they have to treat all those three pages important until analyzed and ruled out as nonimportant....huge waste of time which nobody is up for. At least make an effort to get an answer. :D

Comment: True. Try to be precise with the question.

Comment: Here is a link to some code I've used for this purpose in the past: http://forum.cs-cart.com/topic/32556-how-can-i-make-a-menubar-fixed-on-the-top-while-scrolling/page__view__findpost__p__170375

Answer (score 1):

Use the `position: fixed` css property. Then the position of the div is relative to the window's viewport rather than the content of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You spelled position in #navigation wrong in your stylesheet, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy if you correctly understand how the position attribute works in css.

I have a demo which should help you. You just need to understand how **position:fixed** is used to make the menu bar stick to top.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mvGqf